# how do you measure the effectiveness of an interaction model applied to an app

Tags: interaction-design, interactive-ui, microinteractions

i'm working on an interaction model for an e-commerce app. This includes screen transitions and micro interactions.

My question is what are the potential measurable benefits of implementing an interactions model to an app? and how can these be measured?

Answer (score 1):

I think the true measure of any interaction model/design is to **understand how easily and efficiently the user can attain the desired goal.**

You can measure this through usability testing - both qualitatively and quantitatively.

For qualitative measure, you can conduct a [**think aloud exercise**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/thinking-aloud-the-1-usability-tool/). This will tell you the thought process of the user as he is interacting with your model and will give you insights regarding the ease and friendliness of your model.

For a more quantitative study, you can conduct **[task-time studies](http://www.measuringu.com/blog/task-times.php)** and measure it with [adjusted waldo method.](http://www.measuringux.com/adjustedwald.htm) This will give you insights into the efficiency of your interaction model.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the only quantitative measure of the effects of any UI interaction is the change (positive or negative) in user behaviour.

A/B tests are one of the best ways to get clear reporting of how the changes are affecting user behaviour. The matrixes can be widely different.

The most common one is conversion rates in case of the call to action methodologies. If the changes you suggested/implemented are creating higher conversions (clicks, purchases, subscriptions, downloads or anything that applies to your solution), then it's safe to say that your solution is more "effective". It can also be measured simply by comparing numbers from testing both solutions in a real and/or simulated environment.

This can be applied on pretty much any UI changes. A/B testing is an industry on its own now. The measurement of impact can vary from time spent on page to purchases made by users - depending on the results you can report and discover exact impact of changes you've made.